# Highlighted color not getting overriden by OnDrawItem WindowsForms c#

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, checkedlistbox

```
protected override void OnDrawItem(DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.DrawBackground();
        //This would have to feel the ractangle, it does so, but default (blue) highlight color is still there
        if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {
            using (Brush brush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(40, 40, 40)))
            {
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);
            }
            e.DrawFocusRectangle();
        }

        //SystemColors.Highlight = Color.Gray;

        this.CheckOnClick = true;
        DrawItemEventArgs e2 =
        new DrawItemEventArgs
        (
            e.Graphics,
            e.Font,
            new Rectangle(e.Bounds.Location, e.Bounds.Size),
            e.Index,
            e.State & ~DrawItemState.Selected, 
            e.ForeColor,
            e.BackColor
        );  
        

        base.OnDrawItem(e2);
    }
```

This code is for overriding **CustomCheckedListbox** settings so the highlighted color would either dissapear or be different color.
It does fill the ractangle but only the **Checkbox** part.

My question is how would I **disable** affect of **highlighting**, or make it to just override the highlight color?

Comment: base.OnDrawItem() does [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/CheckedListBox.cs,744).  Teaching CheckedListBox new tricks isn't easy.

Comment: I know I am late to the answer, but after I do `this.OnDrawItem(e2);` my whole program just crashes.